# Change background color on display of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three divs showing/hiding one after the other. What I want is that when one particular div displays, the background color of the page changes. Plus the change is made smooth thanks to a `transition-duration`.

As you may guess, the `gradient-low` color would display at the same time as the `low` div, and same thing for the others. One difficulty I have is that the different divs are not showing in the same order every time (i.e. a `low` div could be followed by a `high` div, then by `moderate`, etc. It's random.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#low").on(function() {
    $("#low").css("gradient-low");
    $("#moderate").hide();
    $("high").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.gradient-low {
  background: #ddd6f3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #faaca8, #ddd6f3);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #faaca8, #ddd6f3);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.gradient-moderate {
  background: #ff6e7f;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #ff6e7f, #bfe9ff);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff6e7f, #bfe9ff);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.gradient-high {
  background: #EECDA3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #EF629F, #EECDA3);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #EF629F, #EECDA3);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="low">
  <h3 class="level">Low</h3>
</div>
<div id="moderate" style="display: none;">
  <h3 class="level">Moderate</h3>
</div>
<div id="high" style="display: none;">
  <h3 class="level">High</h3>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner in jQuery/javascript and you might guess that I'm having some difficulties. Any help on the process would be appreciated.

Comment: How are the divs appearing one after the other? Your call to `on()` is lacking an event name so will not actually do anything

Comment: Thing is it's totally random (it's a music player that changes intensity of music randomly). So after a "low" div there can be a "moderate" div but also a "high" div. This is the main reason why I don't really know where to go with my jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

you would need something like that

```
function showLow() {
  $('body').addClass('gradient-low').removeClass('gradient-moderate').removeClass('gradient-high');
  $('#moderate, #high').hide();
  $('#low').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`infiniteLoop = false` // Set whether animation should keep on triggering
try adding this to your css it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

- You should show or hide div based on what .gradient-* class the body has.

Here is an example, level will be changed every 3 seconds. The changeLevel function has a if else statement which sets display property of div and add or remove gradient-* class in body.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").addClass ("gradient-low");
  function changeLevel () {
    if ($("body").hasClass ("gradient-low")) {
      $("#low").css ("display", "none");
      $("#moderate").css ("display", "block");
      
      $("body").removeClass ("gradient-low");
      $("body").addClass ("gradient-moderate");
    }
    else if ($("body").hasClass ("gradient-moderate")) {
      $("#moderate").css ("display", "none");
      $("#high").css ("display", "block");
      
      $("body").removeClass ("gradient-moderate");
      $("body").addClass ("gradient-high");
    }
    else {
      $("#high").css ("display", "none");
      $("#low").css ("display", "block");
      
      $("body").removeClass ("gradient-high");
      $("body").addClass ("gradient-low");
    }
    setTimeout(changeLevel, 3000);
  }
  
  setTimeout(changeLevel, 3000);
});
```

```css
.gradient-low {
  background: #ddd6f3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #faaca8, #ddd6f3);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #faaca8, #ddd6f3);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.gradient-moderate {
  background: #ff6e7f;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #ff6e7f, #bfe9ff);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff6e7f, #bfe9ff);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.gradient-high {
  background: #EECDA3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #EF629F, #EECDA3);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #EF629F, #EECDA3);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="low">
  <h3 class="level">Low</h3>
</div>
<div id="moderate" style="display: none;">
  <h3 class="level">Moderate</h3>
</div>
<div id="high" style="display: none;">
  <h3 class="level">High</h3>
</div>
```